Texcount: How to provide word count that should see punctuation as letters
For example, I want "half/half" to count as a single word instead of 2 words.
I've tried adding -alpha=digit,alphabetic,punctuation but punctuation throws unknown script ignored error, but I can see in the source code there is a Is_punctuation sub routine in the pl file.
Any hints about how to include punctuation as letters would be helpful.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Welcome! Please add a sample LaTeX file that is similar to the real document with the current and the expected output of texcount. This makes it easier to understand what you want and to test solution attempts.

There seems to be a bug in texcount 3.1.1, 2018 Oct 28, that prevents you from achieving what you want. I have just reported the bug; until a fixed version becomes available, do the following.

Make a local copy of texcount. Under Linux, I do
$ cp "$(which texcount)" my_texcount


In my_texcount, search for the function Is_punctuation. In its body, replace the line
-007b\007e

by
-007b\t007e

thus adding the character t after the backslash.


After this patch, try
./my_texcount -alphabets=Digit,alphabetic,punctuation document.tex

As an example, if document.tex contains
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
half/half
\end{document}

then the command my_texcount document.tex yields
...
Words in text: 2
...

whereas the command my_texcount -alphabets=Digit,alphabetic,punctuation document.tex yields
...
Words in text: 1
...


I'll just confirm that this is the right fix!
